# disable mouse visualisation in Gnome

Tags: mouse

When I press the Ctrl Key, I can visualise my mouse pointer. Is there any way to disable it? So, if you press and release the Ctrl key ( basically its a Key Release event ) , then you see some funny thing on the mouse pointer.

any ways to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

unity-tweak-tool needs to be downloaded to disable this feature. Open Tweak Tool, go to Keyboard and Mouses and then disable "Show location of pointer".

Virtual Box doesnt seem to go along with the feature and hence the Ctrl Key doesnt work at all there.